# Naming our robot

Tags: discussion

So we have this poster, and I am curious to know what you all think we should name our robot.  **Please, one post, with one name suggestion per person.**  We don't want this to get too far out of hand.

[image]

Comment: It might be a bit early for this considering the design isn't final yet...

Comment: What's the girl's name?

Comment: @elemtilas Pandora.

Comment: https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3201/naming-our-lady?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Slartibotfast

Which is, of course, a play on Slartibartfast, a famous World Builder.

Comment: I like it.  So...would we call him *Slarti?*

Comment: This would go well with my suggestion of "Maggie" on http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3201/naming-our-lady?lq=1

Answer (score 12):

I immediatelly connected the robot with name

### Laika

Which was name of first dog in cosmos, and it could make people to "Like" the robot. Also, I like the idea of robot being female.

Comment: to me Laika sounds pretty gender neutral if I look at it objectively, that's why I like it

Comment: +1 for gender neutral / feminine name AND a dog AND exploration / leadership.

Answer (score 11):

**Quasirobo**

With credit to Monty Wild for the [original suggestion](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3116/49).

Answer (score 6):

Looks like a

**Daneel**

to me. I hope you [get the Asimov reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R._Daneel_Olivaw).

Comment: +1, Daneel was fully human looking though...

Comment: I like this answer, although I suggest changing it to just Daniel, so that it isn't a complete copy.

Answer (score 6):

### Jeremy

I derived this name from the name **Jenkins**, as many Worldbuilding users also are programmers that know this tool (though the connection isn't really important).

I wanted to keep the "butler-y" feel that this name carries, as robots usually are used as servants and helpers for humans. The poster, however, also creates the impression of friendship and guidance between the robot and the human (What's her name, anyway?) so I wanted to choose a name, that seems somehow close and trustworthy. Something you could call a friend.

Comment: Why not just call it Jeremy Jenkins? Or JJ? That might make the connection a little more real, and understandable. After all, people love names with clever connections. Also, JJ Abrams.

Comment: Great idea :) I like it!

Answer (score 6):

Let's see how people like the name:

### Quasimodo

since I think that this 'bot looks rather like a hunchback.

Comment: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/3130/49

Answer (score 5):

**Jebediah** old biblical name for a futuristic robot

Comment: Sounds kind of western

Answer (score 5):

#### Alphonse

a reference to [Full Metal Alchemist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fullmetal_Alchemist) character.

Comment: Every time I hear that name, I want to scream it. ALPHONSE!

Comment: Yeah I like this one

Answer (score 4):

### The Machine

World builders used to have to solve their own problems... Then we developed a machine to answer all of our problems. Just like in those books written by the guy with sideburns!

Answer (score 2):

## Arya

because when we get onto suggesting names for the woman in the photo, I'm going to suggest [Alynn](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/15036/alynn-the-scientific-mage-science-principles) - this goes nicely with that. Also, who says that bot's male?

Also, it's a cool name. Why not?

Comment: While I would support whatever gender the robot identifies itself as, it just doesn't look like a woman to me, much less an Arya. I definitely agree with the human's name though, that part should definitely happen.

Comment: Its a robot, it doesn't have a gender...unless its one of *those* kind of robots.

Comment: @James don't be robotist. It might identify as a female piece of copper.

Comment: Sorry, Arya, is 9 year old girl on the path of the Noble Art of Assassination. Not a big robot building worlds...

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin um...where did that come from?

Comment: @ArtOfCode really?... A Song of Ice of Fire, or also known as Game of Throne.

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin huh, that'll be why... haven't read/watched any of it.

Comment: Arya is also a character in Christopher Paolini's Inheritance series- an elf princess and the protagonist's love interest.

Comment: @ArtOfCode It's only female if the copper has a negative charge. Electrons are female, because they always stay in pairs. My science teacher comes up with the strangest analogies.

Comment: The apparent female is in (1) a desert, with (2) a 'droid of some sort, and (3) a long staff.  You mean to say that she isn't Rey?   {Sadness}

Answer (score 1):

## Manitou

After the [great spirit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manitou) and giver of the land in Algonquin traditions.

Answer (score 0):

## The Builder

After all, we are world builders, and this machine's function could be in aid or execution of the building of a world. That's what the hologram it is projecting suggests to me.

Nah, who am I kidding? I'm just inspired by Futurama's Bender.

Comment: Renan this is from 2016...