# Can opinion based questions be posted on the meta?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I was just wondering, can opinion based questions be posted on the meta? Or is it discouraged here like it is in regular world building?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some meta questions are inherently opinion-based.  Yes the close reason is available, but the same base set is present on every site, main and meta, on the network, so I wouldn't read too much into that.

Questions about our scope, about what our policy should be on some point, or for that matter about [what to name our robot](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3102/28) will evoke opinions.  That doesn't make them wrong.  Answers should still *support* those opinions in some way; just saying "unicorns should be off-topic" doesn't help anybody.  And questions still need to be *about the site* (or the SE platform in general); don't use meta to ask people what their favorite movie-worlds are.

See [what is meta?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) in the Help Center for more about the purpose and use of meta.

Comment: If you really want to talk about peoples' favorite movie-worlds, try [chat]. :-)

Comment: This is a difference in definition I think. If you're supporting "those opinions in some way" then it's not **primarily** opinion based. It will be an opinionated answer *based on reasoning* (which is why the reasoning must be included). All answers will contain one portion or another that is opinion based, but if the question solicits answers that are **primarily** opinion based, then it's not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

**Nope.**

Questions about the Worldbuilding main site that are primarily opinion based are not on-topic here on Meta. We still have an option to close questions here as "primarily opinion based". Though I think we're far more lenient here.

If you mean Worldbuilding questions (but would be off-topic on the main site) that are not about the Worldbuilding main site, the answer is still **no**. Those would both be off-topic and primarily opinion based.

Comment: A lot of [tag:discussion] questions are entirely opinion-based but on-topic.

Comment: @HDE226868 Yes, as long as they are *about the site itself* or the software that runs it. Note that on [meta], the top "off-topic" close reason is *This question does not appear to be about Worldbuilding Stack Exchange or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network, within the scope defined in the help center.*

Comment: @HDE226868 No, not entirely. They may be opinionated, but are (or should be) *based on reasoning*, not primarily opinions.