# Can we remove the Meta "opinion-based" tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons, meta

### **[Looking at a query](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuildingme/query/edit/618937) of all closed meta questions, it seems we've never used the opinion-based close reason on meta.**

This site has been up for years, yet we've never found an "opinion-based" question in need of closing. **So why don't we remove that option?**

[Can opinion based questions be posted on the meta?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3117/can-opinion-based-questions-be-posted-on-the-meta) seemed to conclude that there are many opinion-based questions here, as a result of the [discussion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) tag, but that [off-topic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/off-topic) questions absolutely still exist. **It's not appropriate to close questions as opinion-based on this site.**

It is ideal to justify claims in meta with **reasoning**, but having a [discussion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) tag opens the flood gates per se. If we actually enforce the opinion-based close reason on here, we'll have significantly fewer questions! And that's why we've never enforced it. It's easiest to discuss ways to improve the site when opinions can be given.

I'm requesting a **complete removal** (if possible) of that reason to close meta questions.

Comment: I voted to close this question as "opinion-based" in order to let this question answer itself. :-)

Answer (score 5):

The "built-in" close reasons -- duplicate, too broad, primarily opinion-based, and unclear -- are built into the SE software and are used on all sites, main and meta.  This also applies to the "generic" off-topic reasons.

You're right; this close reason doesn't make much sense on meta.  I won't say it *never* applies; I think I've seen it, though I don't recall any details.  But SE has historically not shown much interest in making tweaks like this.  Its presence doesn't impede our use of meta; it's just an option we get used to ignoring, and can continue to ignore.