# Naming our lady

Tags: discussion

Along the lines of [Naming our robot](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3102/naming-our-robot), we should also try thinking up names for the other character on the poster, the Lady of Worldbuilding.

Same rule applies - **one post, one name suggestion per person**.

[image]

Comment: I just noticed, why is the robot wearing shoes?

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh You don't expect it to risk its little robot feet going around barefooted, now do you?

Comment: Actually, is that really a robot as opposed to a gray alien with armor?

Comment: At this rate, I do hope, the final design will keep those two guys ;-)

Comment: She looks a bit like a Lemming... (My god, I'm old...)

Comment: I do think the _thing_ shaped rock structure in the foreground should change. Just saying...

Comment: Is that another lady standing way up on top of the robot's back? Looks a bit like one.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Pandora

She was given a jar, and warned to not open it.

She opened it...

Perfectly in the curious spirit of a worldbuilder.

Answer (score 12):

What about...

...[drum roll](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=alice)...

## Alice!!

Comment: Heh. We're all using series now, eh?

Comment: I upvoted this one, Alice works on several levels.

Comment: I don't get why you limited the search on your posts, if you only search for alice it really shows how much the name is used for "everyday female human". I like the idea nonetheless, upvote. (maybe the joke just rushed past me because I am new)

Comment: I don't know, using names from people's personal series just kind of seems like self promotion to me. Even though I know that it probably isn't intended that way at all.

Answer (score 5):

*Maggie*, as in Magrathea, the planet of planet-builders from HHGG

Answer (score 4):

## Alynn

As a hat-tip to a [brief series of questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/15036/alynn-the-scientific-mage-science-principles) I wrote a while back. I can see the scientific mage and her pet robot being a great force for good.

Comment: I keep on pushing the upvote button, but it doesn't go any higher than +1...

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Didn't you get a sockpuppet army set for the election? ;)

Comment: I'd upvote, but can't get over Alin being a male name in Romanian.

Comment: @SerbanTanasa Now that you mention it, how is this name supposed to be pronounced? I always assumed it was like a - lynn, but I guess it could be pronounced like Allan or even Ellen.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh The former. The y acts as an i.

Answer (score 2):

**Pixie**

She just looks like a pixie to me, no reason beyond that :)

Comment: Oh yes, she does!

Answer (score 2):

## Calliope

As our lady offers a refreshing design of the muse of epic poetry.

Answer (score 1):

### Terra

Its Latin for Earth afterall

Answer (score 0):

I want to suggest **Athena**, the goddess of wisdom, courage, inspiration, civilization, law and justice, mathematics, strength, war, strategy, the arts, crafts, and skill.

Why? Because she rappresents lots of the things a world builder has to think about when he builds worlds and because of the symbols she rappresents.

- Wisdom: the information needed, the things the people/aliens in your world know.
- Courage: to do a thing lots of people think it's strange and crazy
- Inspiration (does it need an explanation?)
- Civilization: of the ones you make
- Law: the rules a worldbuilder decides to follow
- Matemathics: to build the world as precise as possible
- Arts: Worldbuilding is an art!

Comment: Without offense to her, I have to say she doesn't *look* very godly.

Comment: I've edited the answer to explain why I choose her. Hope my English was good enough to let me explain and not to make my choice less understandable. She doesn't look very godly? Well, when in mythology gods choose to walk between mortals they don't look very godly, so I think it's fine.

Answer (score -1):

## Atahensic

Because nothing encompasses world building like an [Iriquois creation myth](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atahensic). Giant turtles, birds carrying people, magic trees, and the beginning of humans.

Comment: Among many others to choose from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Creator_gods

Comment: @cobaltduck I just looked stuff up and this was the first name that caught my fancy.

Answer (score -1):

### ***Lem***

First thing I noticed when I looked at her is that green, wavy hair. That remembered of the iconic creatures that fight for survival on a extremelly harsh world - The Lemmings. No, not the critter, but the game.

Yes, I'm that old.

Still, that's what looks she is trying to do: surviving in a harsh world. She lost her friends and family, but came to know  a nice, kind hearted robot.

And it's a new name!

Answer (score -2):

I love the idea of using a character that has already been created by the users (I'd also love if the robot and lady become the protagonists of every hypothetical setting in questions!), but just to widen the pool a bit I thought I'd suggest the World Builder created by one of the greatest world builders ever:

## [Kin Arad](http://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Kin_Arad)

For anyone not bothered to click the link, Kin Arad is the name of a character of Terry Pratchett's (in Strata) who is responsible for the construction of worlds. Seems apt :)

Note: I know there was brief discussion on avoiding any potential copyright issues, but I figure if anyone is going to be fine with it, it'd be the Pratchetts!

Comment: It's a good name, but I can't in good conscience upvote it because it *is* a copyright issue.

Comment: Yep I figured that might be an issue but thought I'd list in anyway