# What will we lose with the redesign?

Tags: support, design

Inspired by the discussion [Exactly which features of SFF.SE's magnificent theme will we be losing?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11844/exactly-which-features-of-sff-ses-magnificent-theme-will-we-be-losing) I want to ask which features WorldBuilding.SE will lose specifically. The reason I ask basically the same question here again is that I remember that WorldBuilding was often mentioned as one of the "Cadillac" sites with an [extensive design](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2916/worldbuilding-site-design) that will lose quite a bit more than many other sites. And there is already quite a lot that all the sites will lose. To cite the SFF post I linked:

> We will probably be losing our voting buttons, fave button, possibly our use of Orbitron font, and reduced color/header image support.

More details can be seen in the [Meta.SE discussion *Left nav, responsive design, and theming next steps*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309349/left-nav-responsive-design-and-theming-next-steps?cb=1), but I have the same questions as @CreationEdge on SFF.SE:

> Can we get a breakdown of what exactly we'll be losing? Or a time-frame on when we'll be able to see a development version of what we'll be losing?

Especially a little comment in the [answer from @JourneymanGeek](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309430/352819) prompted me to wonder about the changes that will be relevant for *this site*:

> and *cough* I know you guys will keep the worldbuilding robot, right?

What will happen to [Slartibotfast](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3102/naming-our-robot?answertab=votes#tab-top) and [Pandora](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3201/naming-our-lady?answertab=votes#tab-top) (also known as [May Suthers](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-brutal-builder-5fbfbad08c2a))?

Comment: FYI, I [did some kremlinology](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11846/36526) over on SFF.SE which might be of interest to Worldbuilding.SE as well.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks, nice analysis!

Comment: I thought the girl's name was Alice...I'm pretty sure Alice had more votes a year ago.

Comment: Glarnak save us....

Answer (score 5):

Well, looks like they removed the robot and the lady.

There's a [answer on MSE that mentions and asks for their return and I strongly recommend y'all to make your voices heard on the subject](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312427/135565) by voting appropriately

Comment: I am upvoting this answer because it answers the question. But I leave this comment to voice my disagreement with us losing our dear friends! Thank you very much for mentioning this, time to go to MSE!