# Site background image flicker

Tags: bug, design

While scrolling up/down a page, the background image no longer flows smoothly like it used to. At least, I thought it used to.

The image to the left, of the robot and the person with the long hair and flowing cloak in desert now jumps and flickers when scrolling, moving with the page then snapping back into place. It was a slight annoyance at first, but it is getting to the point where it is bugging my eyes now and makes me want to do something else just because of the extra eye strain.

Thanks to @Michael Kjörling and @Molot I am providing more details:

I have found the same thing that Molot suggests in comments. It **works fine in Internet Explorer** (problem does not manifest there), but the **problem exists in Edge**. This explains why I used to be fine and recently noticed the change; I have been using Edge recently instead without even realizing I made the switch.

OS is Windows 10.

Also, because of the comment by Michael Kjörling I will update the post he linked to concerning the theme.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this.  Does it happen in all browsers (and on all devices, if you use more than one)?  Any details you can add about your environment will help in tracking it down.  Thanks.

Comment: Is it just for WB? Have you tried other sites with the new theme and a custom background? Does scrolling another, non SE site have the same effect?

Comment: Issues with the new Worldbuilding SE theme should be posted as answers to [Worldbuilding's updated site theme is live for everyone!](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6744/29), as per the instructions in that post.

Comment: Just to share, [Pandora](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3201/naming-our-lady?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Slartibotfast](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3102/naming-our-robot/3129#3129) are their names :)

Comment: I confirm this to happen on Microsoft Edge. Does not happen in MS Internet Explorer or Firefox. Windows 10 fully updated, don't know how to tell Edge version.

Comment: Apparently it's a known problem with Edge and fixed position elements: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/5752059/