# Floating robot bounces a lot

Tags: feature-request, design

I like the robot who floats in the lower left corner of the page. But he bounces during scrolling. A lot.

(Update: I was using Edge. With Firefox the robot stays in place.)

I believe web designers had this figured out. Instead of repositioning with javascript on every scroll event, pin it in place with CSS absolute positioning. It looks better. No bouncing.

Another update: This other meta question also covers this: [Site background image flicker](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6810/site-background-image-flicker)

Comment: Rather than posting this as a new question, which is basically only visible to WB.SE people (who have no ability to address the issue), it needs to be deleted and posted as an answer to [this question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6744/worldbuildings-updated-site-theme-is-live-for-everyone) from user Catija, who works for SE and is involved in this very issue, so that she can follow up with it.

Comment: This is in no way a problem with this site. This is a bug in Microsoft Edge. Scroll slower or change browser and you're good. Stack developers can't help you, I'm afraid. Also, assumption you made is false. Robot is held in place by CSS `background-attachment: fixed,scroll,scroll;` on `body` element.

Comment: *"This is a bug in Microsoft Edge.*" Not worth the effort to fix then. Let's wait until Microsoft releases [their chromium-based browser](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/12/06/microsoft_edge_chromium/), and have a false hope that they won't screw it up.

Comment: @Renan Weird to be on the other side of this argument, but hoping that the entire world uses Chromium is backwards and dangerous. The Web should be built on standards, not a single piece of software. If web developers get comfortable with building "works for me on Chrome, so get lost" web sites we will all be worse off.

Comment: @zanlynx there is still Mozilla, Safari and the phantom of the Opera. It's not like the 10 people who still use Edge will be making a dent in any market share when it gets axed.