# Who is Slartibotfast?

Tags: discussion

I was reading [Responsive Design Themes - What can sites customize and how can they get changes implemented?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319274/439712) and came across this:

> - Worldbuilding - their robot, Slartibotfast, was a major part of their site identity, so we were sure to incorporate it into the design by letting it float at the bottom of the page.

Who is Slartibotfast? Are they a bot like the community bot? What's their history?

Comment: Who is Slartibotfast?  Oh, for the sake of Glarnak!

Answer (score 20):

> Who is Slartibotfast?

If I am not mistaken, it should be the guy below

[image: Slartibotfast]

Again my assumption, named after [Slartibartfast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slartibartfast)

> Slartibartfast is a character in The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy, a comedy/science fiction series created by Douglas Adams.
>
> Slartibartfast is a Magrathean, and a designer of planets.

Pretty appropriate for worldbuilding, isn't it?

Comment: Ah yes, now you mention it...

Comment: Yes though he mostly did the fiddly bits around the coasts of fjords.

Answer (score 14):

As L.Dutch mentions, that's the name we gave to the robot you can see on the left side of your browser. The name was chosen as

http://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3102/naming-our-robot/3104#3104

The woman on his side, is named Pandora.

Comment: I applaud your genius in naming the robot!

Comment: 'The woman on his side, is named Pandora.' A special Pandora, or just the greek myth Pandora with the box?